# Drawing/Text Editing tool with panning and zoom facility with relative cursor size

Tags: text-editor, drawing, diagram

I want to make a conceptual (Blueprint) diagram of an application architecture in detail.
What I want is a canvas where no matter to what extent I zoom-in or zoom-out, the text cursor size should remain same (***newly typed text should be visible at all levels of zoom***).

The idea is to start with a lot of zoomed in canvas, write some text, insert picture, wrap it all in a box1, then zoom out to extent where the contents inside the box1 is barely visible and then make the similar boxed item and connect it via line with the previous box1(now small).

**But the core requirement is at the Box2 level, the newly written text should be of the same visible size as of in case of making Box1.**

This is the best I could explain my requirement.

*Some related hints ->*

1. A chip design which can be zoomed a lot but still may contain text at each level of zoom.
2. Visio is a great tool but does not meet my core requirement.

Any help would be highly appreciated.